# Can WebAPI project host multiple APIs?

Tags: identityserver4

Ignoring the user and focusing on the client - in order to secure a WebAPI project with ID4 you can add the token authenitcation middleware and then:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });
```

Is it possible to use the same WebAPI project to secure an additional API?

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api2";
            });
```

Or is the ratio between ResourceAPI and a "WebAPI host project" 1 to 1?

Basically, at the client level I was curious if you could create multiple APIs for different clients but use the same WebAPI host project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider a resource to be a *logical source* that needs to be protected.

This means that the resource isn't bound to one WebApi, but the WebApi is bound to one resource. You can create a group of WebApi's that together form the resource. Or you can simply add the complete source to one WebApi.

It then makes no sense to put multiple resources into one WebApi. If it doesn't belong to the resource then create seperate WebApi's.

However, if it does belong to the same resource and you want to divide the resource in logical parts, then use *scopes* instead.

You can add multiple scopes to one resource:

```
resource = Api0
    scope = Api1.Read
    scope = Api1.Write
    scope = Api2.Read
    scope = Api2.Write
```

Please note that I used 'Api0' as the resource name (options.ApiName). Where ApiX may be a logical division per client.

Now I can create seperate WebApi's that are part of the same resource (they all have `options.ApiName = "Api0"`), or one WebApi.

In case of seperate Api's, where each Api implements one scope, I can use something like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ApiName = "Api0";

        options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                if (!context.Principal.HasClaim("scope", "Api1.Read"))
                    context.Fail("Invalid Scope");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

While in case of one WebApi with multiple scopes I can use Policies:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
...
.AddAuthorization(p =>
{
    p.AddPolicy("Api1.Read", (policy) => policy.RequireScope("Api1.Read"));
    p.AddPolicy("Api1.Write", (policy) => policy.RequireScope("Api1.Write"));
    p.AddPolicy("Api2.Read", (policy) => policy.RequireScope("Api2.Read"));
    p.AddPolicy("Api2.Write", (policy) => policy.RequireScope("Api2.Write"));
});
```

Where you can use the AuthorizeAttribute:

```
[Authorize("Api1.Read")]
```

Please note that scope != resource. The client requests one or more scopes, e.g. `"Api1.Read Api1.Write"`, but the resource is validated by the name (audience=Api0).

The events, policies, middleware can be used for finer grained authorization.

Comment: What is `RequireScope`'s namespace?

Comment: @Sasan Add the `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` package, namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`.

Comment: Thank you I used `policy.RequireClaim("scope","{value}")`