# ASP.NET Core API Controller Action validation of IndentityServer4 client permissions/claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have a scenario where multiple clients have access to the same ASP.NET Core API . I.e. the same scopes. They are, however, not permitted to access the same data. If I could identify which client is accessing the API then it could validate whether it had access rights or not. I assume though that this is a bad approach - though doable in my scenario - because it requires code changes when new clients are added. Is there a way to have clients with bearer tokens having claims that I can read in my controller action? How do I configure this is and how do I access the claims in the API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can WebAPI project host multiple APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934854/can-webapi-project-host-multiple-apis)

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, the question is not about multiple APIs but about multiple clients using the same API - where the data the clients are allowed to manage depends on the clients claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with IdentityServer so can't answer to the part about adding claims.

However once the user has claims, you can access it in your api quite simply:

```
[HttpPost("foo/{bar}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(string bar)
{
    var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;//use whatever kind of claim type you want.
    return await DoSomeWork();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx @bruno. The issue is, however, not regarding users but clients. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html#client

Comment: I didn't realize at first that you answer was the correct answer to the question. Due to the naming "Controller.User" I simply didn't consider it at all. But you're right. It also contains the identities and claims of clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the client id(`aud` claim in token) to principle in `OnTokenValidated` event of `AddOpenIdConnect` extension .

In your MVC client , modify the OIDC configuration :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.Scope.Add("api1");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {

        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {
            var clientID = ctx.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "aud")?.Value;

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("ClientID", clientID)
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

    };
});
```

Then you could read the client id in controller like :

```
var clientID = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "ClientID")?.Value;
```

With `using System.Linq;` for `FirstOrDefault` Linq operation .