# How to secure endpoints on api resource based on client in identityserver

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

I have my own authorization server built on top ***identityserver4*** where I want to secure all apis on a host. System is just a simple mimic of google developers or facebook developers where application owners sign up and get client id and client secrets for access grant on apis.

So I followed *client_credentials* flow on identityserver4 samples. All working fine. I built a public UI for app owners to create apps and choose which apis to access from their apps. I make use of `IConfigurationDbContext` for CRUD procecces on internal tables of identityserver.

The problem is I couldn't find a way to secure apis based on app owners' choices, when a developer crate an app and choose a few logical endpoints to access, they still can reach all enpoints. What I have done is as follows;

**Authorization Server Startup**

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
              .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
              .AddInMemoryCaching()
              .AddOperationalStore(storeOpitons =>
              {
    storeOpitons.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
      builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"),
      sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
})
              .AddConfigurationStore(storeOptions =>
              {
    storeOptions.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
      builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"),
      sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
});
```

**Saving Client Method**

```
public IActionResult SaveApp(ClientViewModel model, List<SelectedApi> selectedApis)
{
    //ommited for brevity

    Client client = new Client
    {
        Description = model.Description,
        ClientName = model.Name,
        RedirectUris = new[] { model.CallBackUri }
    };
    client.AllowedScopes = selectedApis.Where(a => a.apiValue == "true").Select(a => a.apiName).ToList();
    //e.g : client.AllowedScopes = {"employee_api"};

    _isRepository.SaveClient(client, userApp);

}
```

**Api Project Startup**

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer(opt => {
    opt.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    opt.Audience = "employee_api";
    opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

});
```

**Api Sample Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepoistory;

    public EmployeeController(IServiceProvider provider, IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository) : base(provider)
    {
        _employeeRepoistory = employeeRepository;

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetEmployees([FromQuery] EmployeeResourceParameter parameter)
    {
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>>(_employeeRepoistory.GetAll(parameter)));
    }
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult GetEmployeeById(int id)
    {
        var emp = _employeeRepoistory.GetById(id);

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<EmployeeModel>(emp));

    }
}
```

What I want is if a developer choose employee_api, they should just reach to EmployeeController's endpoints. However right now, they can reach all the apis no matter of what their choices are.
What are the steps to take for this on api side or auth server side?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get it done.. First of all, I realized that it is important to grasp the relation between `ApiResource -> Scopes`, `Clients -> AllowedScopes`. I suggest you to read the parts about them in the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) and [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/01/new-in-identityserver4-resource-based-configuration/)

When a client is registered to identityserver and then choose the api endpoints (*eg: organization, employee, calender*) they should be registered as allowedScopes of client (*they live in ClientScopes table*), I was doing it in right way. What I was doing wrong is I suppose all these scopes are ApiResources (*for my case, because all my apis are living in the same host which I call it as CommonServiceApi, just one web api app*). I redefined my ApiResources and its Scopes, as follows;

```
new ApiResource("commonserviceapi", "Common Service API")
{
    Scopes = {
        new Scope("calender_api", "Calender Api"),
        new Scope("employee_api", "Employee Api"),
        new Scope("organization_api", "Organization Api"),
    }
}
```

On the api side, endpoints should be authorized with policies as indicated [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html#validating-scopes).
Within the access token, **allowed scopes** of the requesting client are passed to the api app, so api grants accesses according to these values.

So Api **Startup**

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
    opt.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    opt.Audience = "commonserviceapi";

    opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiEmployee", builder =>
    {
        builder.RequireScope("employee_api");
    });
    options.AddPolicy("ApiOrganization", builder =>
    {
        builder.RequireScope("organization_api");
    });
});
```

And Api **Controllers**

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ApiEmployee")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : BaseController
{
    ...
```

`RequireScope` is an extension method of `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` package by the way. You should include this package to your api project.

And lastly, this was a confusing point for me; while requesting an access token from server, scope parameter **should be empty**, as identityserver takes it from client's allowdScopes values. Almost all samples were filling this field, so you'd think it should be filled.

Comment: The last remark is not correct. While by specification the scope parameter may be empty, it's also allowed to request specific scopes. It doesn't have to be empty. Not sure why you think it should. What is confusing from the documentation is that they use one resource/scope with the same name. Make sure the scope name is used, not the resource name. The scope name is used to determine the audience (resource name) while each requested scope is added as claim `scope=employee_api`. Take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934854/#52939428) for more information.

Comment: I wish I find your answer before, very well explained. I didn’t mean to that your scope parameter **should always be empty**, just for this case as this allowedscopes are coming from the client’s allowed scopes dynamically, you must left this scope param empty. This is what I pointed out.